# Why does the screen with turtle graphic close down by itself

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Why does the screen with turtle graphic close down by itself?

```
import turtle
circle = turtle.Turtle()
circle.color("pink")
circle.pensize(5)
circle.speed(5)
circle.circle(10)
circle.done()
```

Comment: `circle.done()`?

Comment: I am pretty sure that in my some previous codes it doesnt turn of despite circle.done()

Answer (score 1):

Instead of circle.done(), put turtle.done()

Answer (score 0):

The turtle window closed by itself because your program ran into an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'done'
```

Use `turtle.done()` instead:

```
import turtle
circle = turtle.Turtle()
circle.color("pink")
circle.pensize(5)
circle.speed(5)
circle.circle(10)
turtle.done()
```

See the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.done).